# Checkpoint function error in R- arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 38, 37

Tags: r, azure-data-lake

I need to create libraries for HighDimout and it's dependencies. This will be used to keep my code on ADLA ( Azure data lake Analytics). I am using checkpoint function from checkpoint package created by microsoft.

```
mm <- checkpoint(snapshotDate="2017-10-17")  

Scanning for packages used in this project
- Discovered 1 packages
Installing packages used in this project 
 - Installing ‘HighDimOut’
HighDimOut
Error in data.frame(timestamp = Sys.time(), snapshotDate = snapshotDate,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 38, 37
```

I am not able to resolve this issue. I  tried -
https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/checkpoint/issues/243 and find my code is not having this problem. Here is the R session session information-

```
 sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] checkpoint_0.4.3  strucchange_1.5-1 sandwich_2.4-0    zoo_1.8-2         modeltools_0.2-22 mvtnorm_1.0-8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] coin_1.2-2       lattice_0.20-35  codetools_0.2-15 MASS_7.3-50      multcomp_1.4-8   Matrix_1.2-14
 [7] splines_3.5.1    TH.data_1.0-9    tools_3.5.1      survival_2.42-3  compiler_3.5.1

> 